# Cloud-based Java IDE that supports Android Development?

Tags: java, android, ide

Me and a friend are looking to develop an Android app, but the catch is, we want a way to simultaneously code, like the editing in a Google Drive document. A great example seems to be [UmbrellaSDK](http://www.umbrellasdk.com) from what I've researched, but we're hoping to develop without having to pay for anything. Then there's Github, but we'd have to upgrade from free to micro for private development and it doesn't have simultaneous editing with others users. The requirements for the IDE we are searching for is pretty much:

- Simultaneous editing with another user
- Saving our workspace to the cloud
- Basic IDE functions, like syntax highlighting
- Support for libraries and other APIs
- Android development support

Comment: Have you looked into [Cloud9](https://c9.io/)?

Comment: And the question is..?

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus Is there such an IDE

Comment: @mc10 From what I've read, it doesn't seem to be any bit directed towards android development, is it?

Comment: Also, how does GitHub fit into any of this? GitHub just stores Git repos; it isn't an IDE.

Comment: I assume you mean Github not Guthub. Bitbucket provides the same functionality with free private repos, up to 5 (I think) collaborators; but neither has simultaneous editing.

Comment: @mc10 Many recommend it as a good place to store a workspace/project to the cloud then working on a file from it privately on your own computer, then updating

Comment: @EliAlgranti I'll look into it, read a bit about it, just seemed to be like Github

Comment: Why do you need simultaneous editing, as opposed to using a standard VCS such as git, svn, or mercurial?  Lots of sites have free hosting, including GitHub, Google Code, BitBucket, and many others.  As mentioned in the comment above, BitBucket even has free private repositories.  Almost any IDE will also have integration with whatever system you use, so you could use whatever IDE suits you.

Comment: @CalebBrinkman It's more convenient, as if we were sitting next to eachother, then using something such as skype for easy communication

Comment: @user1483574 I see how it's possibly more convenient, but I see how it will definitely cause a lot of problems.  You would only be able to see simultaneous edits if you were both working on the same file, in which case one of you would be very likely to accidentally break something the other is working on.

Comment: @CalebBrinkman That's what the easy communication is used for, letting each other know exactly what were doing at that second in time to prevent the breaks.

Comment: [Koding](https://koding.com/?c=ideh) provides a standard Ubuntu VM with full root, browser Terminal & editors supporting basic features (syntax highlighting, folding, etc) for a wide array of languages. It's pair programming features are standard. So Koding supports basically every language out there if it runs on Ubuntu, but previewing Android might still be interesting. Let me know how it works!

Answer (score 2):

[Floobits](https://floobits.com/) is a Y-Combinator backed startup, that provide emacs/vim/sublime plugins for you to allow pair programming. You can use your favorite editor with rich plugins, e.g., syntax highlighting.

Free plan only provides **public repos**, but public here means public under flootbits.com, so who can find your project?

> Your public workspaces are listed under your user profile, like https://floobits.com/u/ggreer/. If someone knows your username, they can see your public workspaces under your profile page.

I've not tried Floobits by myself, so please let me know if it works fine :)